# How to suppress creation of copyFields while indexing csv via POST tool in Solr 7.5?

Tags: solr

7.5 on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm trying to index several large CSV files, millions of rows each, and facing several problems with managed-schema. Using a small test file and specifying the fieldnames, I was able to index but found copyFields of type string were automatically created for all fields. Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

EDIT: I tried copyFields=false to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of the automagic creation of fields - define your fields before importing the documents, then [Disable automatic field guessing](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/schemaless-mode.html#disabling-automatic-field-guessing).

> Automatic field creation can be disabled with the update.autoCreateFields property. To do this, you can use the Config API with a command such as:
>
> ```
> curl http://host:8983/solr/mycollection/config -d '{"set-user-property": {"update.autoCreateFields":"false"}}'
> ```

Comment: Not exactly. I defined my fieldnames in the -params to the POST statement. What happens is (a) fieldnames with no data get dropped - this would be a problem later if I have to remember to add fieldnames every time I add data. And more importantly (b) each field gets a copyField. - which is needless bloat I do not want. How do I suppress automagic **copyFields**?  Also I tried disabling field guessing earlier by manually setting autoCreateFields to false in solrconfig.xml - update failed with "Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id". But field-guessing isn't the problem.

Comment: Well, the `copyField` instruction is created as part of the automagic field detection feature. If you do not want that to be created (and for production use, this should always be the case), defining the fields is what you want to do. If you want to modify _only_ the `copyField` behavior, you can create a copy of the update processor as shown in the link above, and remove the instructions in point 5 (which creates the string field) - and then set that new processor to be used as the default update chain. If you_don't_ have an id column, the uuid or signature processors can help.

Comment: The reason why using the automagic field creating feature isn't recommended for production is for example if a field have a numeric value the first time it's seen, but it can actually contain alphanumeric characters. This will make imports fail when the first non-numeric character is encountered, requiring an explicit schema change and reindexing previous documents.

Comment: It looks like light at the end of the tunnel....  but why make a copy of the update processor and remove the copyField generator, point 5, from there? Or did you mean keep a copy of the original in case I fubar?

Comment: Sure, there's nothing stopping you from modifying the existing one. Just remember that config sets are shared across collections, so it'll be modified for any other collection using the same set of configuration in that case.